# cleveref crashes with special character

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I read chapter 10 of the `cleveref`-manual and thought, that my following code would work, but it crashes. The special character can't be handled by cleveref.

Did I made a mistake? Or is there a solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{ü}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm} \label{dummy}
test
\end{thm}

See \Cref{dummy}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Eh... you're changing the question! Of course `beforeüafter` won't work as the environment name (at least not in this way!)

Comment: Ben: Yes, of course, but I could guess you would not get much encouragement for this. I am a German native speaker and have no worries using English command names, as long as the typesetting output is using German names.

Comment: Environments' names should only consist of letters (and possibly of standard printable ASCII characters such as `*`). Avoid accented letters that also make typing awkward, for the simple reason they *don't* work.

Comment: @Ben: Really? It should fail to compile, in my opinion, even without `\Cref` etc.

Comment: @Ben No, it doesn't work as soon as you load `inputenc`.

Comment: @Ben That's why I say it's not recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ü` is no single character and is a fragile command actually, but using `\newtheorem{thm}{{ü}}` will work, i.e. grouping the command.

From the screenshot you will see that `cleveref` is really **clever**: It uses the correct uppercase character `Ü` if `\Cref` is applied, although it specified directly!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[ngerman]{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{{ü}}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm} \label{dummy}
test
\end{thm}

See \Cref{dummy} or \cref{dummy}.

\end{document}
```